# gnuplot - filled curve with palette color

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, palette

I'm trying to plot a histogram in gnuplot, where the bars are characterized by their color (intensity) instead of their height (frequency). To do so, I want to fill each bar with a color corresponding to the third column (which stands for this intensity) of a data file, defined in a palette. All the bars have the same height y=1 and the same width dx=1. The important part of the script looks like

`plot for [ii=0:N] 'data.dat' index ii u 1:2:3 w filledcu y1=0 lc palette`

My problem is that the ii=0 takes the right color of the palette and fills the first bar, but from there on all the others are the same color ( same intensity ) than ii=0.

My data file looks like:

*X   Y      Intensity*

1   1    0.6

2   1    0.6

...

Any idea to fill with the right color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filledcurves` plotting style doesn't support color gradients, see [Gnuplot filledcurves with palette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18079836/2604213).

Since you have the same height for every bar, you can use the `boxes` plotting style:

```
set style fill solid noborder
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3 with boxes lc palette
```