# I want to fill my gnuplot plots with variable colors using filledcurves

Tags: gnuplot

This shouldn't be such a big problem, but it appears it is. I have a file with 3 columns - x data, y data and hex color data.

`plot "data" using 1:2:3 with filledcurves x1 linecolor variable`

If I use this code, the line *above* my plot - the border - is indeed colored like that (using the hex color data). However, I want to make sure that the *fill color* is also the same as the line color. Right now it is grey.

Referring to gnuplot help, I read this on `fillstyle`:

> The `solid` option causes filling with a solid color, if the terminal
>    supports that. The `density` parameter specifies the intensity of the
>    fill color. At a `density` of 0.0, the box is empty, at `density` of 1.0,
>    the inner area is of the same color as the current linetype.

I'm interpreting this as following. If I use:

`set style solid 1`

It will make my filling go solid, and copy the color of the current linetype. This linetype currently has the linecolor "variable" set - so it should just copy that value, right? However, it does not.

The basic question to be answered here is:

How do I make specific parts of the `filledcurves` style have a different fillcolor?

Comment: A workaround is to use `boxxyerror`, see the answer at [Gnuplot filledcurves with palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513791/gnuplot-filledcurves-with-palette/70972684#70972684)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature had not been released yet in stable `gnuplot` (2016-01-30).

The similar question and answer with variable filling is shown here:
[Gnuplot filledcurves with palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513791/gnuplot-filledcurves-with-palette)

However, the other solution [adapted from the `feature-request`](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/411/) is

```
stats infile using 2
N = STATS_blocks
set cbrange [0:N]
plot for [poly=0:N-1] "data" index poly using 1:2 with filledcurves x1 fillcolor palette cb poly lw 2
```

Note, to use this solution, you should divide your data into blocks ([2 blank lines between](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-data/) block in the file)

Fortunately, the feature request was resolved yesterday (2016-01-29), so you could try to download the latest code from [CVS](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/code/), compile `gnuplot`, and run smth. like

```
plot 'data' using 1:2:(column(-2)) with filledcurves closed fillcolor palette z
```

[to color data with the value of data index](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/411/).

Comment: Great research! Thanks!